# Why does Mist doest show up anything for me running on testnet

Tags: mist, dapp-development, dapps

I just see a blank screen when I open `Mist Browser` on ubuntu running on `testnet`. What is the issue ?

I couldnt start in the first place. But after using `--ignore-gpu-blacklist` I could start, Then I get the blank Page as in the image below and it doesn’t show up anything.

Its not a duplicate question, I have edited it as per the solutions in the other questions. I had issues with starting `Mist` only when I gave `--ignore-gpu-blacklist` it only started. My blockchain is synced with `testnet` as wel..

[image]

Comment: This question will probably be closed [as a duplicate](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) soon. If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!